# C# Console WriteLine System.FormatException:

Tags: c#, format

```
string CPP_NAME_SPACE = "test"
System.Console.WriteLine("} // namespace {0}", CPP_NAME_SPACE); // FormatException

System.Console.WriteLine("} // namespace {0}"); // normal

System.Console.WriteLine("// namespace {0}", CPP_NAME_SPACE); // normal
```

Why does the first line throw a FormatException but not the second?

Answer (score 8):

The first line throws an exception because it's trying to populate the `{0}` with a value and there's an unescaped brace `}` at the start (it should be `}}` to avoid the exception). The `}` at the start is treated as a formatting code which is incomplete so it cannot process it.

The second line doesn't as there's no value to populate the string with so it prints as is.